# Как изменить select

Tags: vue.js, select

Можете подсказать как задать всплывающему меню select-а задать определенный параметр?
Допустим [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сейчас у меня первый вариант слева, нужно сделать как второй. То есть, если даже в селекте много строк, показывать он должен, скажем 3 строки и рядом полоса прокрутки

Comment: Можете показать css код для этого select'a?

Comment: Необходимо ограничить высоту блока - ```max-height: 200px; overflow-y: auto;```

Comment: css кода пока нет

Comment: не работает(...

Comment: Благодарю @soledar10 эти параметры помогли. Ну а селект написала сама, кастомный